# How do you compute the $w_2$ of Freedman's E8 manifold?

Tags: gn.general-topology, manifolds

The Wikipedia page for Rokhlin's Theorem says

"Michael Freedman's E8 manifold is a simply connected compact topological manifold with vanishing $w_{2}(M)$ and intersection form $E_{8}$ of signature 8. Rokhlin's theorem implies that this manifold has no smooth structure."

Is it easy to see that $w_2(M) = 0$?

Comment: Wu's formula tells you that on a simply-connected $4$-manifold $M$, $w_2(M)$ is characteristic, i.e. $\langle x,x\rangle = \langle w_2(M),x\rangle \pmod 2$. In particular, $w_2(M)$ vanishes iff the intersection form is even, which $E_8$ is.

Comment: How does one define $w_2$ of a topological manifold? Does Wu's formula still hold? (Not that one really needs it for this argument to work, but as phrased it seems relevant.)

Comment: The Stiefel-Whitney classes lift from $BO(n)$ to $BTop(n)$, the classifying space of microbundles, essentially by the definition as the failure of the Thom isomorphism to commute with Steenrod operations. Every topological bundle has a canonical microbundle, which is a lift of the tangent bundle of the manifold is equipped with a smooth structure. See also this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/243629/topological-invariance-of-stiefel-whitney-classes-for-open-smooth-manifolds

Comment: Thank you so much!